# How can I send transactional email using sendy with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ses, transactional-email, sendy

I am developing ruby on rails application and using sendy with amazon ses for marketing campaign.

Is it possible that I will integrate this sendy server as my transactional emails which I am using in my ruby on rails development for welcome email, forgot password and some other emails?

If it is possible then provide me some useful steps for configuration of sendy with ruby on rails for transactional emails.

Would anybody know of a solution?

Answer (score 2):

[Sendy has an API](https://sendy.co/api) that allows you to create a campaign programmatically. You could call it from your rails app. However, the API is restricted to sending a campaign to a **whole list** and subscribing/unsubscribing to an **existing list**. I'm afraid that with these limitations in mind you cannot really do transactional emails.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hello ! Sure, I'm aware of the best practice to copy the relevant material here, but since I'm saying that the function Sachin is asking for doesn't exist, I don't quite know what to copy here. Any guidance appreciated

Comment: @Matthieu Yes. Agree with you. Its not exist.

Comment: @SachinGevariya feel free to accept it as correct answer then if you want